# REGEXP Expressão Regular no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, regex

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Preciso realizar uma consulta **(O site foi desenvolvido no wordpress)** onde tenho várias especialidades de saúde.

Quando um item estiver marcado com duas categorias ele é registrado da seguinte forma no banco de dados: **["1","19"]**, eu preciso filtrar para que os item marcados no 19 não apareça no 1, pois como ambos estão com o número 1 está tendo esse problema. Será que alguém poderia me ajudar? Lembrando que o item 1 e 19 são figurativo, não posso fixa-los pois temos várias categorias, podendo ter **["2","20"]** entre outros.

A consulta está sendo feita assim:

```
$especialidadesaude = empty($_REQUEST['especialidadesaude']) ? 0 : intval($_REQUEST['especialidadesaude']);
$url = 't.categoria = 11';
if ($especialidadesaude != 0) { $url.= ' AND t.especialidadesaude REGEXP "'.$especialidadesaude.'"'; }
$params = array( 'where' => $url, 'limit' => 15, 'orderby' => 't.name ASC');
```

Para que vocês possam entender melhor o problema. Tenho um site de consultar na área de saúde, como drogarias, farmácias, clínicas, etc. Cada um desses itens são categorias setadas por id. No cadastro, o registro poderá estar marcado com mais de uma categoria, como drogarias e farmácias. Se se no cadastro eu marco apenas um categoria no banco de dados ele registrar apenas o ID da categoria, caso tenha duas categorias e grava no banco da seguinte forma: ["10", "11"]. Isso significa que existem duas categorias marcadas. Preciso fazer um filtro para exibir somente os resultados do item 10 e somente exibir os resultados do item 11. Meu problema e saber tratar essa questão por conta do banco gravar o registro da forma citada acima ["10", "11"]. Para fazer a consulta fiz como mencionei acima.

Estou tentando fazer isso com *Regexp*, tentei com *LIKE* e *IN* mas não da certo. Se alguém tiver outra ideia ou solução aceito.

Comment: Saulo, por favor poste o que esta armazenado na variavel `$url e $especialidadesaude`

Comment: Não entendi o que quer exatamente.
Poste algumas linhas que você tem no banco e o resultado que espera.

Comment: Para que vocês possam entender melhor o problema. Tenho um site de consultar na área de saúde, como drogarias, farmácias, clínicas, etc. Cada um desses itens são categorias setadas por id. No cadastro, o registro poderá estar marcado com mais de uma categoria, como drogarias e farmácias. Se se no cadastro eu marco apenas um categoria no banco de dados ele registrar apenas o ID da categoria, caso tenha duas categorias e grava no banco da seguinte forma: ["10", "11"]. Isso significa que existem duas categorias marcadas. Preciso fazer um filtro para exibir somente os resultados do item 10...

Comment: ...e somente exibir os resultados do item 11. Meu problema e saber tratar essa questão por conta do banco gravar o registro da forma citada acima **["10", "11"]**. Para fazer a consulta fiz da seguinte maneira:
`$especialidadesaude = empty($_REQUEST['especialidadesaude']) ? 0 : intval($_REQUEST['especialidadesaude']);$url = 't.categoria = 11'; if ($especialidadesaude != 0) { $url.= ' AND t.especialidadesaude REGEXP "'.$especialidadesaude.'"';} $params = array('where' => $url, 'limit' => 15, 'orderby' => 't.name ASC');
`@IvanNack @RafaelAcioly

Comment: Conseguirão me entender
@RafaelAcioly
?

Comment: Em geral, é preferível usar as funções nativas do WP do que fazer esse tipo de consultas diretas no banco... Chegou a conferir [esta seção do `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com suas descrições, podemos considerar que todos os códigos possuem aspas como `"10"` ou `["10"]` ou `["10", "11"]`.

Se este for o caso, você pode fazer uma consulta com o `LIKE` (escapando as aspas, se necessário):

```php
// AND t.especialidadesaude LIKE "%\"10\"%";
$url.= ' AND t.especialidadesaude LIKE "%\"' . $especialidadesaude . '\"%"';
```

Caso `"` e `[]` sejam utilizados, somente quando houver um grupo de itens, você pode ter códigos aparecendo como `10` e como `["10", "11"]`. Neste caso, você pode utilizar este código:

```php
// AND t.especialidadesaude REGEXP ("10"|^10$);
$url.= ' AND t.especialidadesaude REGEXP "(\"' . $especialidadesaude . 
   '\"|^' . $especialidadesaude . '$)"';
```

Espero ter ajudado.